# ElasticSearch double nested sorting

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have documents which look like this (here is example):

```
{
"user": "xyz",
"state": "FINISHED",
"finishedTime": 1465566467161,
"jobCounters": {
    "counterGroup": [
        {
            "counterGroupName": "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter",
            "counter": [
                {
                    "name": "FILE_BYTES_READ",
                    "mapCounterValue": 206509212380,
                    "totalCounterValue": 423273933523,
                    "reduceCounterValue": 216764721143
                },
                {
                    "name": "FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN",
                    "mapCounterValue": 442799895522,
                    "totalCounterValue": 659742824735,
                    "reduceCounterValue": 216942929213
                },
                {
                    "name": "HDFS_BYTES_READ",
                    "mapCounterValue": 207913352565,
                    "totalCounterValue": 207913352565,
                    "reduceCounterValue": 0
                },
                {
                    "name": "HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN",
                    "mapCounterValue": 0,
                    "totalCounterValue": 89846725044,
                    "reduceCounterValue": 89846725044
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "counterGroupName": "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobCounter",
            "counter": [
                {
                    "name": "TOTAL_LAUNCHED_MAPS",
                    "mapCounterValue": 0,
                    "totalCounterValue": 13394,
                    "reduceCounterValue": 0
                },
                {
                    "name": "TOTAL_LAUNCHED_REDUCES",
                    "mapCounterValue": 0,
                    "totalCounterValue": 720,
                    "reduceCounterValue": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Now I want to `sort` this data to get TOP 15 documents on the basis of `totalCounterValue` where `counter.name` is `FILE_BYTES_READ`. I have tried nested sorting on this but no matter which key name I write in `counter.name`, it is always sorting on the basis of `HDFS_BYTES_READ`. Can anyone please help me with my query.

```
{
"_source": true,
"size": 15,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "state": {
                        "value": "FINISHED"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "range": {
                    "startedTime": {
                        "gte": "now - 4d",
                        "lte": "now"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"sort": [
    {
        "jobCounters.counterGroup.counter.totalCounterValue": {
            "order": "desc",
            "nested_path": "jobCounters.counterGroup",
            "nested_filter": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "jobCounters.counterGroup.counter",
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "jobCounters.counterGroup.counter.name": "file_bytes_read"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

This is the mapping for `jobCounters` we have created:

```
"jobCounters": {
        "type": "nested",
        "include_in_parent": true,
        "properties" : {
          "counterGroup": {
           "type": "nested",
            "include_in_parent": true,
            "properties": {
              "counterGroupName": {
                "type": "string",
                "fields": {
                    "raw": { 
                        "type":  "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
              },
              "counter" : {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "include_in_parent": true,
                    "properties": {
                        "reduceCounterValue": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "english",
                            "fields": {
                                "raw": { 
                                    "type":  "string",
                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "totalCounterValue": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "mapCounterValue": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }                   
                    }                   
                }                    
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

I followed nested sorting documentation of ElasticSearch and came up with this query, but I don't know why it is always sorting the `totalCounterValue` of `HDFS_BYTES_READ` irrespective of `jobCounters.counterGroup.counter.name`'s value.

Comment: Could you share the mapping?

Comment: Shared! Sorry for that :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this,

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index/jobCounters/_search' -d '
{
  "size": 15,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "jobCounters.counterGroup.counter",
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "jobCounters.counterGroup.counter.name": "file_bytes_read"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "jobCounters.counterGroup.counter.totalCounterValue": {
        "order": "desc",
        "nested_path": "jobCounters.counterGroup",
        "nested_filter": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "jobCounters.counterGroup.counter",
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "jobCounters.counterGroup.counter.name": "file_bytes_read"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
'
```

Read the end of [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/nested-sorting.html) document. It explains that we have to repeat the same query in nested_filter too.

Comment: No, it is still sorting on some other field. Moreover, I think in this query sort has no way to know on which ```totalCounterValue``` it has to sort, so it's doing for the first one it gets.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I think you have to check if jobCounters.counterGroup.counter.name matches totalCounterValue before the sorting and in the sorting nested filter. Hope it works

Comment: Unfortunately, even this is not working. It's now sorting on ```FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN``` instead of ```FILE_BYTES_READ```, maybe we need to do something as ```counterGroup``` is an array and also ```counter``` is an array so double nesting?